# Creating android layou with tabs

Tags: android-layout, android-tabhost, android

Does anyone know how to create a layout like the below image. The right hand side portion contains two tabs and the left hand side have a text view.

[image: android layout]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: u can take the help of button and textview

Comment: @Android Killer - That is an easy solution. But i have to use tabs there, not buttons

Comment: If something is easy then u shud go for that. Anyway i dont know that tabs can be done like this. I also like to see if anyone can suggest anything.

Comment: If you are working as a developer for some clients who have a strong IT teams, you have to use components they are suggesting. And thats the case here, else i would have go for buttons.

Comment: In that case u r right. These clients man !!!! they never listen to u. me also in client side now :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that they are tabs. They are actually the menu items on actionbar. If you are looking for tabs then [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have seen that earlier. But problem is that it cannot be placed right to a text view. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: first of all, make it comment else SO guys will dv it.

Comment: @AndroidKiller: I would love to, but I don't have that option since my reputation is not that good till now. I need to score more reputation before making comment

Comment: @AnoopssGolden: As far as I know there is no option like that. But as you have showed in picture, you can do it using actionbar menu.

Comment: But that is not part of actionbar. Action bar contains only app name and a search icon

Comment: @AnoopssGolden: No. I have used it as drop-down menu. Please check for actionbar tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The layout in your picture is the layout of a tabbed application for a tablet.
If you follow this tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

You'll get the tabs on your phone and when you have enough space (tablets) the actionbar and tabs become one.

Comment: But the portion in the picture is not action bar. There is an action bar above it and it contains only application title and a search icon

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but I think because there is a search icon the tabs will automatically go below the action bar, even if there is enough space.